# Windbg: psscor4 doesn't work

Tags: .net, windbg, sos

I searched and tried a lot of things, but can't get psscor4 to work properly.

When I invoke *!threads*, I'm always getting

> Failed to request ThreadStore

The things I checked are as follows:

- I'm having a .NET 4 application that's compiled for X86 platform
- I'm using Windbg version 6.2.9200.16384, X86 version
- I'm using current psscor4 from Microsoft and it loads properly. I'm loading the X86 version, so that should be fine
- Symbols are loaded from MS Symbol server (command *.symfix+*, then *.reload*)
- *.cordll* shows the following:

> CLR DLL status: Loaded DLL C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscordacwks.dll
>   
>   The same happens when I try to use SOS with *.loadby sos clr*

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: attached to process or on a dump?

Comment: What is the build number of the CLR you're debugging (lmvm clr)?

Comment: 1. Attached to a process
2. CLR v4.0.30319

Comment: I need to know the last (4th) part of the build number.  I need to know whether you're debugging .NET 4.0 or 4.5.

Comment: It's .NET 4.0. Full Version of CLR: 4.0.30319.18052

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you're debugging .NET 4.5.  PSSCOR4 won't work with .NET 4.5.  I also suspect that you're running .NET 4.0 on your debugging machine, which would cause your SOS not to work either.  In order to debug .NET 4.5, you need .NET 4.5 SOS and/or SOSEX (which works for all versions of .NET 2.0+).

Comment: You're right! I read that 4.5 is an in-place replacement of 4.0. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: With SOS it doesn't work either.
I load it with _.loadby sos clr_. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need the 4.5 SOS.  You probably have .NET 4.0 running on your machine, so you need to grab SOS.dll from a machine running .NET 4.5.

Comment: That's exactly the confusing thing: I do a live debugging session on my computer, not a dump file from a different computer. Thus, I suppose this should work - the first answer here [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/578dcdfe-080c-4712-a5bc-59744c6d283f/windbg-location-of-sosdll-for-net-framework-45) also tells this.

Comment: You're right.  For a live process, everything should just work.  I'm not sure what else to tell you.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this problem to happen when either:

1. you are running the wrong version of the extension against the .NET framework for the process (!eeversion) - as mentioned by Steve Johnson here. To fix, verify ther version of .NET that the process was using (!eeversion) and download the corresponding correct version AND bitness of the extension.

OR

1. you are not using the correct version of SOS against the memory dump for the process - i.e. your version of SOS is different than the version of SOS on the machine where the dump was taken.  To test this, comapre the result of !eeversion against .chain and see if the SOS version is the same.  If they are not, you make sure your Symbol Search Path in WinDbg is setup correctly and then run .symfix followed by .reload

The Symbol Search Path should be set to something like:

`SRV*C:\SYMBOLS\PUBLIC*http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols;SRV*C:\SYMBOLS\PUBLIC*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

You can also try the solution that is posted on John Robbins' blog here: http://wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/automatically-load-the-right-sos-for-the-minidump

Please note that I was able to get his solution to work only with WinDbg version 6.2+ - version 6.12 and below didn't work.

HTH