# On loading psscor4: The garbage collector data structures are not in a valid state for traversal

Tags: .net, debugging, garbage-collection, windbg, sos

I am debugging Microsoft Word in a live debugging session. The process loads a few managed add-ins so I am using sos and psscor4. The process winword.exe is a 32-bit process but the managed add-ins have MSIL as the value of their PlatformArchitecture enum meaning they are compiled to be JITT'ed on any platform.

I am using Windbg (x86).

As soon as I load psscor4 from the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 directory, and then try out any of the GC related commands, for example the `!clrusage` command, I get this message:

> The garbage collector data structures are not in a valid state for
>   traversal. It is either in the "plan phase," where objects are being
>   moved around, or we are at the initialization or shutdown of the gc
>   heap. Commands related to displaying, finding or traversing objects as
>   well as gc heap segments may not work properly. !dumpheap and
>   !verifyheap may incorrectly complain of heap consistency errors. Error
>   requesting GC Heap data Unable to build snapshot of the garbage
>   collector state.

During the time that psscor4 is loaded, even the sos commands related to GC do not work. For example if I ran the `heapstat`, or `dumpheap` or `eeheap -gc` commands, they do not work.

They resume working as soon as I unload psscor4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PSSCOR does probably not work in your case because your plugin uses .NET 4.5 and [PSSCOR4 was not built for .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18828544/480982). You can check the .NET version with `lm vm clr`. If it shows 4.0.30319.18401 or higher, it's .NET 4.5.

`!heapstat`, `!dumpheap` and `!eeheap` do not work, because PSSCOR4 brings its own versions of those commands. You can verify that with the `.extmatch /e *psscor4* *` command.

It depends on the order of loading extensions which one is the default one. You can display the loaded extensions with `.chain`, the default one being at the top. You can make a different extension the default extension using `.setdll`.

You can also explicitly define the SOS extension to be used with `!sos.heapstat` and similar, if you don't want to change the default extension.

Comment: If someone might explain the downvote, that would be great. I'm glad to learn something new about debugging .NET with WinDbg and SOS.

Comment: Just an FYI: I didn't downvote. I am appreciating every one of your answers and your help. I am still to mull over some of the answers of yours from my previous questions that I haven't marked as right.

Comment: Hurray! Thank you. Would you know of a command from sosex that gives you what `!psscor4.clrusage` did? Upvoted and cancelled that downvote that someone else did.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: the closest is probably `!eeheap -gc`